# Javascript special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an html with a form.
After the user submits the form, the values in the form are sent to a database with ajax.
My problem is that is the user submits the form with a plus sign (+) in one of the fields, the plus sign won't show in the db.

my code:

```
function update()
{
    var branch_id = 1;
    var saleTitle = $("#title").val();
    var saleText = $("#text").val();
    var imgSrc = $("#imgSrc").html();
    var datastr ='branch_id=' + branch_id + '&saleTitle=' + saleTitle +
                 '&saleText=' + saleText + '&imgSrc=' + imgSrc + '&func=update';

         $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "update.php",
         data: datastr,
         success: function(msg){
             //alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
             if (msg == "")
             {
                 $("#message").html("Update was successful!");
             }
             else
             {
                 $("#message").html("Error") + "   " + msg;
             }
         }
     });
}
```

Comment: did you check the data you get server side from the ajax call? You need to check whether it comes from the js (which is the code you are showing us) or from the PHP (but you didn't show us the code you are using)

Comment: The data on the server side is the string without the plus sign.

Comment: What is the column type in your database?

Comment: @nikc.org it's varchar with utf_general_ci encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass an object, not a string.

```
var dataobj = { 
    branch_id : branch_id,
    saleTitle : saleTitle,
    saleText  : saleText,
    imgSrc    : imgSrc,
    func      : "update"
};
// …
data: dataobj
```

Then jQuery will take care of escaping the data (`+` means *a space* in this data format) and concatenating it into the application/x-www-form-urlencoded data for you.

Answer (score 3):

use :  `encodeURIComponent(xxx)` on the field which has the plus sign

```
encodeURIComponent('~!@#$%^&*(){}[]=:/,;?+\'"\\')
```

will result :

```
~!%40%23%24%25%5E%26*()%7B%7D%5B%5D%3D%3A%2F%2C%3B%3F%2B'%22%5C
```

Comment: That will encode the entire query string, not a component of it.

Comment: Actually you should use encodeURIComponent around the individual variables (`branch_id`, `saleTitles`)

Comment: The example is still broken since it assigns the value directly to the data property instead of using it in the query string.

Comment: @Quentin I dont see the problem , I encode it and post it as form post. It will be **BAD** to send it in Query String.

Comment: @RoyiNamir — Your example assigns the output of `encodeURICompoent` to the `data` property. It needs to be merged into the data (e.g. used on the line in the question that starts `var datastr` and not the one that starts `data`).

Comment: @Quentin - yep its because the speed of copy paste. I also wrote explictly to encode :  `on the field which has the plus sign`

Answer (score 0):

You can try jQuery Serialize
    http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: That won't work. Not all the data consists of the values of form fields: `var imgSrc = $("#imgSrc").html();`